# How can I label only the first quarter of each year in ggplot w. geom_text?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I'm trying to create labels in ggplot with geom_point and geom_text, that labels only the first quarter of each year, and no labels in between. The labelled 'dots' should just give the year.

So 2009 + + + 2010 + + + 2011 and so on. I'm sure there is a simple way to do this, but I'm stuck!

I should add that I'm looking to do this "programmatically" and not manually, as I will be doing this for multiple data-sets and several years. Appreciate any help!

CODE:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(pxweb)
library(lubridate)


# Download data from Statistic Sweden

# PXWEB query 
pxweb_query_list <- 
  list("Kon"=c("1+2"),
       "Alder"=c("tot16-64"),
       "Arbetskraftstillh"=c("ALÖS"),
       "ContentsCode"=c("0000062S"),
       "Tid"=c("*"))

# Download data on unemployment and vacancy rates
unemp <- 
  pxweb_get(url = "https://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/en/ssd/AM/AM0403/AM0403A/NAKUBefolkning2KTD",
            query = pxweb_query_list)

# Convert to data.frame 
unemp <- as.data.frame(unemp, column.name.type = "text", variable.value.type = "text")


# PXWEB query 
pxlist2 <- 
  list("Antanstallda"=c("TOT"),
       "ContentsCode"=c("AM0701F4"),
       "Tid"=c("*"))

vacancy <- 
  pxweb_get(url = "https://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/en/ssd/AM/AM0701/AM0701D/KVRekVakStor",
            query = pxlist2)

# Convert to data.frame 
vacancy <- as.data.frame(vacancy, column.name.type = "text", variable.value.type = "text")

rm(pxlist2, pxweb_query_list)

# Fix date-format
unemp$quarter <- yq(unemp$quarter)
vacancy$quarter <- yq(vacancy$quarter)

# Join df's
final <- inner_join(unemp, vacancy, by = "quarter")

# clean names
final <- final %>% janitor::clean_names()

# rename etc
final <- final %>% 
  mutate(unemp = percent) %>% 
  mutate(date = quarter) %>% 
  select(date, unemp, vacancy_rate)

# Seperate data in two periods
final <- final %>% 
  mutate(period = 
           case_when(
             date>=ymd('2002-04-01') & date<ymd('2008-01-01') ~  "one",
             date>=ymd('2008-01-01') & date<=ymd('2015-01-01') ~  "two")) 

ggplot(final) +
  aes(x = unemp,
      y = vacancy_rate,
      group = period,
      color = period,
      label = date) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_path() +
  geom_text() +
  facet_wrap(~period) +
  theme_gray()
```

The result currently looks like this (it's mid-process, I know it looks ugly):

[image]

Comment: It will be easier to help if you can share a sample of `final` instead of all the steps to create it. e.g. run `dput(head(final, 20))` and paste the code that it outputs into your question.

Comment: I'm guessing something like `geom_text(data = . %>% filter(month(date)==1))`

Comment: Great tip. I didn't know this actually!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often the simplest way to do this is just create another `label` variable in your dataframe, and use `ifelse()` to set the labels you don't want to an empty string `""`.

See the example below, where I create `date_label` that is the year when the month == 1, and any other time the label is `""`.

```
final <- final %>% 
  mutate(
    period = case_when(
      date>=ymd('2002-04-01') & date<ymd('2008-01-01') ~  "one",
      date>=ymd('2008-01-01') & date<=ymd('2015-01-01') ~  "two"),
    date_label = ifelse(month(date) == 1, year(date), "")
  )
```

The graph still looks hella ugly, but at least the labels are now right :)
[image]